# Is possible parse the DOCTYPE with Jsoup to discover HTML version?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, doctype

I want to parse the *`DOCTYPE`* of a page with *Jsoup* to discover the version of *HTML* (*HTML 5*, *HTML 4*, *XHTML*, etc.).

Is possible to parse the *`DOCTYPE`* with *Jsoup* to handle it? If not is, there is a way to achieve the main objective that is discovering the version of page HTML?

Comment: What is your usecase? Does it matter that the majority of sites with a Doctype don't conform to the associated specification?

Comment: @Quentin No, doesn't matter. The only thing that will matter is the pages that only uses HTML 5. The other cases are only for purposes of what is declared on the DOCTYPE.

Comment: If it doesn't matter if they conform, why it does matter if they use the HTML 5 Doctype? If the only thing you care about if using the HTML 5 Doctype, why not string match for that?

Comment: @Quentin If they use, so there is an analysis of the HTML5 elements. The other doctypes are only for a statistical purpose. At the moment, I'm doing string match.

Comment: New elements introduced in HTML 5 work even without an HTML 5 Doctype. I don't see the logic of excluding those documents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Jsoup` has `DocumentType` class for this purposes:

```
List<Node>nods = doc.childNodes();
         for (Node node : nods) {
            if (node instanceof DocumentType) {
                DocumentType documentType = (DocumentType)node;
                  System.out.println(documentType.toString());
                  System.out.println(DocumentType.attr("publicid"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to detect version i.e. html5 or html4.0 or something else?
I am getting `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">` for html4.01
and `<!doctype html>` for html5.

So question is do I need to match this string and say it is html5 ot html4.01?

Comment: I did this way :

`private String getHtmlVersion(Document document) {
  List<Node> nodes = document.childNodes();
  return nodes.stream().filter(node -> node instanceof DocumentType).map(this::generateHtmlVersion)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
 }`

and generateHtmlVersion looks like this

`private String generateHtmlVersion(Node node) {
  DocumentType documentType = (DocumentType) node;
  String htmlVersion = documentType.attr("publicid");
  return "".equals(htmlVersion) ? Constants.HTML_5_VERSION : htmlVersion;
 }`
@vacuum your answer helped **+1**